# SQL Oracle - max function

Tags: sql, oracle, join, nested

I need some help with this query, i need to get code name address with the most recent date per code (date1 is < date6 in this example)

**Tab1**

```
   code address
====================
    cod1    addr1
    cod2    addr2
    cod3    addr3
    cod4    addr4
```

**Tab2**

```
    code    date     name
===========================
    cod1    date1    name1
    cod1    date2    name1
    cod1    date3    name2
    cod2    date3    name3
    cod3    date5    name4
    cod3    date6    name5
    cod4    date3    name6
```

So i write

```
SELECT Tab1.code, Tab1.address, Tab2.name, max(Tab2.date)
FROM Tab1, Tab2
WHERE Tab1.code=Tab2.code
GROUP BY
Tab1.code, Tab1.address, Tab2.name
ORDER BY
Tab2.name
```

but I do not get what I want, the same code multiple times with different dates, so I guess a join or a nested select is necessary, but being a little ignorant I'm asking here for help

Comment: Please add expected output as well.

Comment: expected output:
cod1    addr1    name2 date3
cod2    addr2    name3 date3
cod3    addr3    name5 date6
cod4    addr4    name6 date3

Answer (score 1):

You can use either analytics or aggregate functions.

[Analytics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407):

```
SELECT code, address, name, date
  FROM (SELECT Tab1.code, Tab1.address, Tab2.name, Tab2.date,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION by tab1.code 
                                  ORDER BY tab2.date DESC) rn
          FROM Tab1 
          JOIN Tab2 ON tab1.code = tab2.code)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

[Aggregates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901):

```
SELECT Tab1.code, Tab1.address, 
       MAX(Tab2.name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY tab2.date DESC) name,
       MAX(tab2.date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY tab2.date DESC) date
  FROM Tab1 
  JOIN Tab2 ON tab1.code = tab2.code
 GROUP BY Tab1.code, Tab1.address
```

This will select one row for each row in table 1. If there are two rows in table 2 with the same date for the same code, one row only will be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Actually the Analytics you proposed throws a missing expression error
the Aggregates [Err] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Oracle version is 11.1.0.6.0

Comment: @Jarod81 Next time don't use the reserved word `DATE` as one of your column name. Also if you want people to test provide the CREATE and INSERT statement. You can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11184) to build a better complete example. Finally, you have to expect to make some adjustments, I *assumed* that you would replace the fictitious name with real-world column name in the example =).